# How to count number of inversions for large number of inputs using merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I am able to count the inversions for small number of inputs. What changes should I make to count the number of inversions for 100000 inputs.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right);
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right);

int mergeSort(int arr[], int array_size)
{
    int temp[array_size];
    return _mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, array_size - 1);
}

int _mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right)
{
    int mid, inv_count = 0;

    if (right > left)
    {
        /*Divide the array into two parts
         and call _mergeSortAndCountInv()
         for each of the parts*/

        mid = (left + right) / 2;

        /*Inversion count will be sum of inversions in left-part
         right-part as well as number of inversions while merging */

        inv_count = _mergeSort(arr, temp, left, mid); // counting inversions in the left part
        inv_count += _mergeSort(arr, temp, mid + 1, right); //counting inversions in the right part
        inv_count += merge(arr, temp, left, mid + 1, right);
    }
    return inv_count;
}

int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right)
{

    int i, j, k;
    int inv_count = 0;

    i = left; // i is the index for left subarray
    j = mid; // j is the index for right subarray
    k = right; // k is the index for resultant merged subarray

    while (i <= (mid - 1) && j <= right)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j])
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            inv_count = inv_count + (mid - i);
        }
    }

    // copying the remaining parts of the left subarray to temp (if any)
    while (i <= (mid - 1))
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];

    // copying the remaining parts of the left subarray to temp (if any)
    while (j <= right)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];

    // copying back the merged elements to oroginal array ;
    for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }

    return inv_count;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 7, 2, 3, 9, 1 };

    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int ans = mergeSort(arr, n);
    cout << "Number of inversions are" << "\n" << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your mergesort-based routine **works properly** for small inputs, it's able to treat also input of any possible size (hundred millions)

Answer (score 0):

> k = right; // k is the index for resultant merged subarray

There is a problem in this line I guess It should be

> k=left;

So The problem is in the sorting algorithm.
 
Merge Sort's time Complexity is *Nlog(N)* And all you have added is one single line

> ```
>         inv_count = inv_count + (mid - i);
> ```

of constant complexity So it won't change the overall complexity of your algorithm. There won't be any problem in counting the number of inversions in the array even if the inputs are *100000*.